# Visual Studio 2017 crashing on load solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017

My VS 2017 keeps crashing with following error in EventViewer. Any idea why it's crashing?

```
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[[System.Byte, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Byte>)
   at System.Linq.ImmutableArrayExtensions.SingleOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<System.__Canon>, System.Func`2<System.__Canon,Boolean>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioProjectTracker.GetOrCreateProjectFromArgumentsAndReferences(Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.ProjectSystem.IWorkspaceProjectContextFactory, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2<System.String,Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.DeferredProjectInformation>, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2<System.String,System.String>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioProjectTracker.GetOrCreateProjectFromArgumentsAndReferences(Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.ProjectSystem.IWorkspaceProjectContextFactory, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2<System.String,Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.DeferredProjectInformation>, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2<System.String,System.String>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioProjectTracker+<PopulateWorkspaceFromDeferredProjectInfoAsync>d__86.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioProjectTracker+<LoadSolutionFromMSBuildAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.TaskExtensions+<FireAndForget>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(System.Object)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory+SingleExecuteProtector.TryExecute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory+SingleExecuteProtector+<>c.<.cctor>b__20_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Comment: What features did you choose to install?  At what point is VS crashing?

Comment: @Jimmy It worked fine for first time when I loaded the solution. Now every time when I open a solution it crashes. I think it may have something to do with WPF file being opened at startup.

Comment: if you delete (or rename) the .vs folder next to your solution, it should forget which files were open last.  Can you try that and see if the crash still occurs?

Comment: @Jimmy Should make that an answer. Deleting the .vs folder solved the issue for me

Comment: @Jimmy actually just deleting `.vs\SolutionName\v15` folder solved the issue. VS team should look into this issue though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**To work around the issue:**
Try deleting the .vs folder (which is hidden by default) that resides next to your solution file.  *This will make VS forget about any IDE settings for that solution, such as files opened or breakpoint locations.*  If you don't want to lose those, move/rename the directory instead.

**To give feedback and help make the product better:**
Before applying the workaround, try to capture a crash dump for the issue.  Then, report it using the Report A Crash feature in VS or by filing an issue on http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio.

Comment: Wow.  I logged my issue here on VS Developer Community.  The problem appeared after I added 2 .NET Core Web Apps.  They marked as a duplicate and pointed me at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24524/vs2017-rtw-crashing-opening-sln-after-upgrading-nu.html.  The solution was to disable WIFI in the link which kind of worked.  But I've tried the above answer and works 100% of the time so far.  And no mucking about.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue. I'm guessing what caused the issue was that vs was confused because I renamed my solution file so the .vs folder contained configuration for both.