# Visual Studio 2017: Can't open Solution directly

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Yesterday I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 and then installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. Now I have the following problem when I try to open a solution (existings and also if I create a completely new one):

When I open "MySolution.sln" directly per double click or pinned from Taskbar, then the solution opens very shortly but then immediately closes again and I am at the plain Visual Studio start screen.

But when I open the solution from Visual Studio via "Open Solution" dialog, everything works as expected.

Has anybody an idea why this could happen? What is the difference between these 2 opening ways?

**EDIT:** The problem only occurs, when the solution is in a TFS source controlled folder.

Comment: Here I am prompted by Windows 10 for the application to use the first time. Selecting the version selector (which Win10 remembers)... opens in VS2017 fine. Suggest you check the file association for `.sln`.

Comment: Thanks @Richard for your answer. Yes, I was also prompted the first time. There I selected VS2017. But then immediately I hade the described problem...

Comment: Could you start Visual Studio with logging enabled? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4809605/937093). This still works in VS 2017 (just checked). The devenv.exe is, by default, located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Common7\IDE`

The `ActivityLog.xml` should give some more informations on this. Also take a look at Windows's Eventlog, maybe you can spot something in the Application log.

Also which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Thank you Steffen. My Windows version is Windows 10 Version 1607

In the ActivityLog I see nothing really special.

In Event Log I have one suspiecious error:

Comment: Fehlerbucket 125730739576, Typ 5
Ereignisname: PerfWatsonVS12Data
Antwort: Nicht verfügbar
CAB-Datei-ID: 125858063079

Problemsignatur:
P1: PerfWatsonTcdb
P2: 0
P3: 0
P4: 0
P5: 0
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Angefügte Dateien:
\\?\C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTelem.Out\201703101743_D15RTWSVC_15.0.26228.4_9b7f4df716f34d0b869de8c8e968cd7110920.tcdb
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF5A4.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

Comment: could you start two instances of VS2017 (A and B) and attach A to B? (Debug -> Attach to process -> select the process of B). Make sure that all in the exceptions window all boxes are marked so A will break on the first exception. Then open a solution in B.

Also have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40662280/937093)?

Comment: that was a very nice tipp :-) now i see the following exception: "Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.NotInstalledException' was thrown."

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.GetInstalledExtension(String identifier)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Feature.FindVsixVersion(String vsixId) in C:\d\lanes\4368\73f58d6d\source\xamarinvs\src\Features\Feature.cs:line 189

Comment: hmm, if this project contains Xamarin related stuff, could you open the installer on your machine and make sure that everything Xamarin/Android related is installed?

If it is, or if this is not a Xamarin related solution - try to open the .csproj files involved in this by themselves. Meaning, doubleclick them and Visual Studio will/should open (and at least on one of them it should crash - making it easier to figure out the cause for this).

Comment: I uninstalled now everything related to Xamarin and reinstalled it. Still same error :-( And if I try to open a non Xamarin related sln or csproj, then it also crashes, but without throwing an exception :-(

Comment: That's.... Interesting. I'd say let's continue with creating a 'default' solution with one command line project/exe and try opening that while another visual studio is debugger is attached (same as before)

Comment: I found now the probelm: The loading problem only exist, if the .sln is placed inside my mapped TFS workspace folder! I tried to re-mapp my workspace, but that didn't help. But yes, another problem to fix... ^^'

Comment: Could you take a look at the folder where the .sln resides and delete the .suo file in there? Or move it somewhere else and try to open the sln again?

Comment: That didn't help unfortunately. Because I was thinking for a long time to switch from TFS to Git, I did that now. And yes, now everything works. Not a real solution, but it works now for me... Thank for or your Help Steffen!

Comment: weird. Interesting 'solution' though. Maybe the TFS part of your VS installation is 'weird' or there is some bug that occurs when combining VS2017 with the version of TFS you are using.